# Set PyCharm's long line wrap to indent instead of match brace

Tags: python, pycharm, indentation

PyCharm's auto formatter really wants me to use the brace-aligned indentation style for long lines, and I hate it.

What I want is this:

```
lazyLib.print_message("  Collecting {} of {} LBs..."
    "".format(", ".join([str(x) for x in current_numbers]), len(lblist)))
```

And what PyCharm wants to do is this:

```
lazyLib.print_message("  Collecting {} of {} LBs..."
                      "".format(", ".join([str(x) for x in current_numbers]), len(lblist)))
```

How do I set PyCharm's auto formatter to indent my code the way I prefer it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to control wrapping by adjusting the "Align when multiline" settings in Settings > Code Style > Python > Wrapping and Braces.

You can uncheck "Align when multiline" under method declaration parameters, collections and comprehensions, and method call arguments.

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't clear to me what those options meant.  This did what I asked!

Comment: This worked for most things, but not straight strings.  I turned all of the Align options off, but a regular string still want to align in this style when I try to break it up.  Any ideas?